# Function returns an instance of Future<String> instead of String

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a streambuilder, within, I want to calculate the distance for each different card of the streambuilder. It calculates the distance if I print it in the terminal, but on the screen it shows: Instance of future < String >. Is there a fix for this? I tried making a variable and run set state, but the value has to be different for each card of the streambuilder.

```
Future<String> distanceInMeters({double uLat, double uLong}) async {
  if (uLat == null && uLong == null) {
    return "";
  } else {
    double distanceInMeters =
        await Geolocator().distanceBetween(uLat, uLong, 52.3546274, 4.8285838);
    String distance = distanceInMeters.toString();
    return "$distance";
  }
}
```

Comment: can we see the code where you call this method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use a [`FutureBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html). If you are not familar with this widget, you can follow the link to the documentation, which describes the function of the widget extensively.

In practice, it would look something like this:

```dart
FutureBuilder(
    future: distanceInmeters(uLat: uLat, uLong: uLong),
    builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasError) return Text('${snapshot.error}');
      if (snapshot.hasData) return Text('${snapshot.data}');
      return const CircularProgressIndicator();
    },
  )
```

The reason you need this is that you are returning your `String` value from an **asynchronous** function and thus you need to have some logic that waits to extract the result from the `Future`.

Comment: Tested the code, but got the text: Futurebuilder <String>

Comment: @KarelDebedts You need to use this as a widget and not pass it as a string.

Comment: @KarelDebedts How would I know? If you want me to investigate that, you should share the place you are using the widget (probably ask another question).

Comment: I am in the exact scenario, below are my codes: 
Container(child: distanceText(),) -- where the widget is called  @creativecreatorormaybenot. 

  Future<String> getDistance(
      lat, long, lat1, long1) async {
    return geolocator.distanceBetween(lat, long, lat1, long1).toString();
  }

  Widget distanceText() => FutureBuilder(
        future: getDistance( lat, long, lat1, long1),
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) return Text('${snapshot.data}');
        },
      );
getting on text: Instance of 'Future<double> not text